# Passing client MAC addresses to DHCP server over VPN

Tags: vpn, dhcp, gateway, static-ip

I'm tasked with implementing VPN access on a gateway. The LAN DHCP server is configured to assign the same IP address to a given MAC address. I would like to have this functionality for clients who connect over the VPN. I know I can configure openVPN and strongSwan to use a 3rd party DHCP server, but do daemons use the client MAC address for the DHCP request? Everything I've read doesn't go into this detail, but I imagine it would use the TAP interface MAC address. Am I wrong about this? How much work would it be to configure/patch the VPN server software to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with openVPN, any traffic from clients in ethernet bridged mode using 3rd party DHCP is passed with the client's tap0 mac address intact. So if the client has a consistent mac address for their tap0 adapter, you can then allocate them the same IP everytime. I'm not sure if the same behaviour occurs using openVPN's built in DHCP.